# How to tell if my localhost server has been hacked?

Tags: windows-7, xampp

I run a development environment on my windows 7 PC using [xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html).

For one of the sites that I have been developing, I have embedded a [disqus](http://disqus.com/) widget. I just received a disqus comment on this site that is running on my *localhost*. This would seem to imply that my localhost is somehow open to the world. I've no idea how this is even possible.

What do I need to check? What steps do I need to perform? Would a hijackthis log be useful?

Comment: Do you have firewall enabled?  Port Forwarding on your router to your PC?

Comment: Yes, windows firewall enabled and no port forwarding on the router

Comment: If you visit http://localhost/security/ are there any "unsecure" items?

Comment: Unless you have multiple devices connected to your router then port forwarding is more often then not actually NOT required for software to function.  There is also the fact routers have for a very long time supported UPnP and you likely have a public server.  So unless you have configured Apache NOT to be public to the internet it likely IS public to the internet.

Comment: The title and question are about two different things. The title asks about how to tell if your system has been hacked; the question seems to be about whether your Apache is accessible to the world. Those are very different questions with completely different answers.

Comment: Right, on the assumption that Apache is accessible to the world, then how do I check that? I'm sitting in a rental office and connect through their router.

Comment: Alternatively, is is possible for someone to comment on a disqus widget, but not on my site?

Comment: @Kinetic - You can't without access to a seperate device.

Answer (score 0):

Right, I got hold of disqus support, and this is what they had to say:

> Yes, it is possible for anyone to use your forum shortname, unless you
>   explicitly set your domain as the ‘Trusted Domain’ in your forum
>   settings here

Whew.